# Tap-able tile that highlights when tapped and all others are un-highlighted

Tags: flutter, dart

I used ListView.builder to create a horizontal list of tiles but I'm trying to make it such that when one is tapped the previously selected one is un-highlighted. In other words only one can be selected at once.

Someone gave me a snippet to try with `selectedIndex = -1;` and it kinda works but after a few times you need to tap the item twice before it is highlighted but tbh I don't truly understand how it works.

```
class FoodDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Food food;

  FoodDetail(this.food, {super.key});

  @override
  State<FoodDetail> createState() => _FoodDetailState();
}

class _FoodDetailState extends State<FoodDetail> {
  bool selected = false;
  int selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
      color: kBackground,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.food.name,
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              _buildIconText(
                Icons.access_time_outlined,
                Colors.blue,
                widget.food.waitTime,
              ),
              _buildIconText(
                Icons.star_outlined,
                Colors.amber,
                widget.food.score.toString(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          Row(
            children: const [
              Text(
                'Variations',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: widget.food.variations.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.food.variations[index].selected =
                        !widget.food.variations[index].selected;
                    if (widget.food.variations[index].selected) {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    } else {
                      selectedIndex = -1;
                    }
                    if (widget.food.selectedVar != null) {
                      widget.food.selectedVar = null;
                    } else {
                      widget.food.selectedVar = widget.food.variations[index];
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: widget.food.variations[index].selected &&
                              index == selectedIndex
                          ? kPrimaryColor
                          : Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          widget.food.variations[index].imgURL,
                          width: 52,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          widget.food.variations[index].title,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          Row(
            children: const [
              Text(
                'About',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(
            widget.food.about,
            style: const TextStyle(
              wordSpacing: 1.2,
              height: 1.5,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIconText(IconData icon, Color color, String text) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          icon,
          color: color,
          size: 20,
        ),
        Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Food class

```
class Food {
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  int price;
  int pq;
  int quantity;
  bool favourited;
  List<Variation> variations;
  Variation? selectedVar;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
  Food(this.imgUrl, this.desc, this.name, this.pq, this.waitTime, this.score,
      this.price, this.quantity, this.variations, this.about, this.favourited,
      {this.highlight = false});
}
```

Variation class

```
class Variation {
  String title;
  String imgURL;
  bool selected = false;
  Variation(this.imgURL, this.title);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overcomplicating your implementation.
Your `Variation` class already has a `selected` boolean, just use that.
No need to track the `selectedIndex`, you can discard that variable.

Change your code inside the `setState` like this:

```
  SizedBox(
    height: 100,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.food.variations.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            /// you first set all variations to false
            widget.food.variations.forEach((e) => e.selected = false);

            /// then you set the tapped one to true
            widget.food.variations[index].selected = true;

            if (widget.food.selectedVar != null) {
              widget.food.selectedVar = null;
            } else {
              widget.food.selectedVar = widget.food.variations[index];
            }
          });
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: widget.food.variations[index].selected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  widget.food.variations[index].imgURL,
                  width: 52,
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.food.variations[index].title,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

and also on your `color` property now you just check for `selected`,
this fixes your issue.